# Spyder very slow in debug mode

Tags: python, spyder

Python 3.10.6, Spyder 5.4.3

the slow-down is about 20x.  this is a new, clean stand-alone install; details below.  I can't find anything online reporting this issue, any insights would be appreciated.

everything else works, can run programs in spyder, execution time is normal, but when running in debug, the slow-down is 20x or more, even with no breakpoints set.  No sure how to approach this problem.

this is a new upgrade to ubuntu 22.04.  the included spyder doesn't start in that release, so i followed the instructions here:

https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html#using-pip

```
 sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove spyder
 python3 -m venv spyder-env
 source spyder-env/bin/activate
 pip install spyder numpy scipy pandas matplotlib sympy cython
```

```
(spyder-env) ~$ pip list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ---------
alabaster                     0.7.13
arrow                         1.2.3
astroid                       2.15.3
asttokens                     2.2.1
atomicwrites                  1.4.1
attrs                         23.1.0
autopep8                      2.0.2
Babel                         2.12.1
backcall                      0.2.0
beautifulsoup4                4.12.2
binaryornot                   0.4.4
black                         23.3.0
bleach                        6.0.0
certifi                       2022.12.7
cffi                          1.15.1
chardet                       5.1.0
charset-normalizer            3.1.0
click                         8.1.3
cloudpickle                   2.2.1
comm                          0.1.3
contourpy                     1.0.7
cookiecutter                  2.1.1
cryptography                  40.0.2
cycler                        0.11.0
Cython                        0.29.34
debugpy                       1.6.7
decorator                     5.1.1
defusedxml                    0.7.1
diff-match-patch              20200713
dill                          0.3.6
docstring-to-markdown         0.12
docutils                      0.19
executing                     1.2.0
fastjsonschema                2.16.3
flake8                        6.0.0
fonttools                     4.39.3
idna                          3.4
imagesize                     1.4.1
importlib-metadata            6.6.0
inflection                    0.5.1
intervaltree                  3.1.0
ipykernel                     6.22.0
ipython                       8.12.0
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
isort                         5.12.0
jaraco.classes                3.2.3
jedi                          0.18.2
jeepney                       0.8.0
jellyfish                     0.11.2
Jinja2                        3.1.2
jinja2-time                   0.2.0
jsonschema                    4.17.3
jupyter_client                8.2.0
jupyter_core                  5.3.0
jupyterlab-pygments           0.2.2
keyring                       23.13.1
kiwisolver                    1.4.4
lazy-object-proxy             1.9.0
MarkupSafe                    2.1.2
matplotlib                    3.7.1
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
mccabe                        0.7.0
mistune                       2.0.5
more-itertools                9.1.0
Mosek                         10.0.40
mpmath                        1.3.0
mypy-extensions               1.0.0
nbclient                      0.7.3
nbconvert                     7.3.1
nbformat                      5.8.0
nest-asyncio                  1.5.6
numpy                         1.24.3
numpydoc                      1.5.0
packaging                     23.1
pandas                        2.0.0
pandocfilters                 1.5.0
parso                         0.8.3
pathspec                      0.11.1
pexpect                       4.8.0
pickleshare                   0.7.5
Pillow                        9.5.0
pip                           22.0.2
platformdirs                  3.2.0
pluggy                        1.0.0
prompt-toolkit                3.0.38
psutil                        5.9.5
ptyprocess                    0.7.0
pure-eval                     0.2.2
pyarrow                       11.0.0
pycodestyle                   2.10.0
pycparser                     2.21
pydocstyle                    6.3.0
pyflakes                      3.0.1
Pygments                      2.15.1
pylint                        2.17.2
pylint-venv                   3.0.1
pyls-spyder                   0.4.0
pyparsing                     3.0.9
PyQt5                         5.15.9
PyQt5-Qt5                     5.15.2
PyQt5-sip                     12.12.1
PyQtWebEngine                 5.15.6
PyQtWebEngine-Qt5             5.15.2
pyrsistent                    0.19.3
python-dateutil               2.8.2
python-lsp-black              1.2.1
python-lsp-jsonrpc            1.0.0
python-lsp-server             1.7.2
python-slugify                8.0.1
pytoolconfig                  1.2.5
pytz                          2023.3
pyxdg                         0.28
PyYAML                        6.0
pyzmq                         25.0.2
QDarkStyle                    3.1
qstylizer                     0.2.2
QtAwesome                     1.2.3
qtconsole                     5.4.2
QtPy                          2.3.1
requests                      2.28.2
rope                          1.7.0
Rtree                         1.0.1
scipy                         1.10.1
SecretStorage                 3.3.3
setuptools                    59.6.0
six                           1.16.0
snowballstemmer               2.2.0
sortedcontainers              2.4.0
soupsieve                     2.4.1
Sphinx                        6.1.3
sphinxcontrib-applehelp       1.0.4
sphinxcontrib-devhelp         1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp        2.0.1
sphinxcontrib-jsmath          1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5
spyder                        5.4.3
spyder-kernels                2.4.3
stack-data                    0.6.2
sympy                         1.11.1
text-unidecode                1.3
textdistance                  4.5.0
three-merge                   0.1.1
tinycss2                      1.2.1
toml                          0.10.2
tomli                         2.0.1
tomlkit                       0.11.7
tornado                       6.3.1
traitlets                     5.9.0
typing_extensions             4.5.0
tzdata                        2023.3
ujson                         5.7.0
urllib3                       1.26.15
watchdog                      3.0.0
wcwidth                       0.2.6
webencodings                  0.5.1
whatthepatch                  1.0.4
wrapt                         1.15.0
wurlitzer                     3.0.3
yapf                          0.32.0
zipp                          3.15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with the latest version of Spyder 5.4.3 vs 5.2.2

submitted to github:
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/20862

there is a 30x slowdown of pandas execution in Spyder 5.4.3 when in debug mode, only 4x with 5.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Per https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/20571 "I can confirm reverting to ipython 7.33 made debug run much faster." the solution is to revert to ipython 7.33.

To do that for Anaconda (open the Anaconda prompt on Windows):

```
conda install ipython=7.33.0 -c conda-forge
```

It is not fully clear to me if you need the latest conda-forge version. You may be able to get away with:

```
conda install ipython=7.31.1
```

For pip I did not test but I assume this will work:

```
pip install --force-reinstall ipython==7.34.0
```

If it doesn't work you need to uninstall ipython then reinstall the specific version. But again I didn't pip to try.